# Is there a good way use the group-by key to look-up something in another polars dataframe in a groupby context without using apply?

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I have two polars dataframes, structured like this:

One is `source_df`, structured loosely as below, with many rows (e.g., hundreds of thousands) per key.

```
┌─────────────┐
| Key | Value |
| --- | ----- |
| k1  | v12   |
| k1  | v12   |
| k1  | v13   |
...
| k2  | v21   |
...
```

and the other is `metadata_df`, structured loosely as below, with only one row per key.

```
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
| Key | lower_bound | upper_bound | outlier_model_fitted_stat_1 | ... |
| --- | ----------- | ----------- | --------------------------- | --- |
| k1  | lb1         | ub1         | omfs1                       | ... |
| k2  | lb2         | ub2         | omfs2                       | ... |
...
```

The values in `metadata_df` can be pre-set by the user, and otherwise will be null in the dataframe as present in this function and appropriately computed based on the values in `source_df` of the appropriate key. Some of the columns in `metadata_df` will dictate the final values of other columns in that dataframe if both are fit---e.g., a different upper bound will dictate what values are included in fitting the outlier model, etc. A description of the kinds of columns in `metadata_df` and the steps needed to compute them are below, all of which are done per key over the values in `source_df`, and should happen in sequence as they impact subsequent steps.

1. Filter (set to NaN) or censor values in `source_df` on the basis of whether or not they exceed bounds set by the user in `metadata_df`.
2. Infer the `value_type`---whether the values in `source_df` are mostly integers or floating point values---and adjust them accordingly prior to downstream processing. If the value type is set in `metadata_df` by the user, that should be used instead.
3. Determine if the numerical values should be converted to categorical, if there are insufficiently many unique numerical values. This property can also be pre-set by the user.
4. For values that are still numeric, fit custom outlier detection models. Use these to filter remaining outliers. Pre-set outlier detector models can't be pre-set by users.
5. Fit normalization models over the values. Pre-set normalizers can't currently be pre-set by users.

The result of these 5 steps yields a new row in `metadata_df`, with a categorical entry for value type, and struct fields (that are potentially large) for outlier model parameters and normalizer model parameters. As there is only one row per key in `metadata_df` but hundreds of thousands of rows per key in `source_df`, I'm wary of doing a join at the outset as that would duplicate all of the data in `metadata_df` upwards of thousands of times on average.

I'm trying to determine what the best way is to perform these preprocessing steps in polars, without using apply and UDFs to avoid that slowdown. My current options:

1. I could call `source_df.join(metadata_df, on='Key')`, then construct a polars expression to only fit the metadata columns if (after the join) they are non-null (indicating they aren't pre-set by the user), but this seems inefficient, as that would result in duplicating the information in the appropriate row of `metadata_df` across all rows of `source_df` of the same key.
2. Unstack `source_df` out to have a column per key (e.g., a column for the value for key `k1`, a column for the value for key `k2`), then iterate through all columns and do the lookup into `metadata_df` manually per column. This also seems inefficient as the blow-up will result in an incredibly sparse dataframe and the iteration won't take advantage of polar's native parallelization efforts.
3. Use `.all()` after the groupby then join that dataframe to `metadata_df` to avoid the unnecessary data duplication, then process the values column of series via the `.arr` accessor. However, this doesn't seem like a good idea as the `.arr` accessor doesn't have the same methods as the full expression syntax does, and I think the `.all()` aggregation in `groupby` may also have implications on the laziness/parallelization of other aspects of the query which I don't want.
4. Separate the `metadata_df` calculation into different groupby steps, using a filter in advance to remove keys per step if values are pre-set by user, then have the groupby aggregation not need to be joined with `metadata_df`, and only compute the necessary updates, which would be output as a dataframe with one row per key. This would split the single groupby into many, but avoid the join.

Is there a better way to do this than one of those I propose here? If not, which of the two is likely to be the most efficient in practice? Also, does this matter at all given I'll eventually need to do a full join later when using the fit metadata columns to transform the data values for final pre-processing?

I have a current solution that is working using `apply` and a UDF that does the lookup manually. It is still much faster than the same solution in pandas, but I feel it is likely much slower than it needs to be and hope to find something better. Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: You should the `python` and `dataframes` tags to your question for more exposure.

Comment: Are you saying `k1` can appear multiple times in `df_source` - and this is the duplication you're trying to avoid? Perhaps you're looking for a [semi-join](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/howcani/combining_data/joining.html#semi-join)? e.g. `metadata_df.join(source_df, how="semi")`

Comment: Yes, `k1` can appear multiple times in `df_source`; however, a semi join isn't what I want because the many values that appear for key k1 are necessary to compute the updates to the columns in `metadata_df`.

Comment: Okay. Well I'd guess the first method (join) would be more efficient but the best thing to do would be to time it yourself on your dataset to see how it performs.

Comment: Ok, thanks, @jqurious. Barring other ideas by folks, I'll try a few options and report back on time / memory implications.

Comment: @MarceloPaco Strong disagree.  The polars solution will not look anything like a pandas or base python solution.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott Without a better sense of what the data looks like or how you're filtering, it's pretty hard to say much. If you need all the data in `df_source` then I'm not sure why you say it's wildly inefficient to do a join.  You talk about `explode`ing your `df_source`, does that mean the value is an array?  If so then you probably want to explode and join.  In general though, unless you run out of system memory, the best approach is *usually* to make big sparse dataframes and then filter them down as needed. Maybe this case is the exception to that but it probably isn't

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Thanks for the info. I added more detail in the post about the structure of the data. My concern regarding the join is that `source_df` may have upwards of hundreds of thousands of rows per key (e.g., 100k+ rows with key `k1`), so joining the `metadata_df` row for `k1` to that dataframe would duplicate it 100k times. If I can skip that join, and just compute the aggregate output for `k1` in a groupby, this duplication can be avoided. And thank you for the catch -- I meant unstack, I think not explode -- have one column for the values of `k1`, one for those of `k2`, etc.

Comment: Have you tried to join them and it crashed?

Comment: To follow up on this, I ended up splitting up this operation into a multi-stage process with explicit joins to avoid needing to look up anything by the group by field, and it was fine. This is likely sub-optimal, as that does result in duplicating the joined columns across identical groupby instances, but it was ok in my use case.